# Magento secure trading payment method need to hold a payment option

Tags: magento-1.7, payment-gateway, paylater

In my magento store have many customers. I want to offer my old customer with this special option.

(i.e) **No need to pay at the end of the sale**. They can pay later with their outstanding invoices by online mode. Is there any possible to set this option with magento store.

I m using Secure trading payment gateway.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The way to go here would be, I guess, to assign them to a specific customer group and then enable payment methods by customer group.

This is not default Magento however. You can either do this yourself by editing either the Payment block class in Checkout or the Payment template checking for the current customer group and suppressing any that are not allowed.

Or optionally use a ready to go extension for which you can check out following extensions: [N98 Checkout Filter](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/netz98magento/extension/7590/n98_customergroupcheckout) or [Amasty Shipping and Payment](http://amasty.com/shipping-payment-by-customer-group.html). I've only worked with the first one myself and from what I can recall it worked pretty well.